# Impulse travelling faster than light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

There have been conducted many experiments in which light impulses traveled faster than light like the one in Princeton in 2000. This phenomenon has something to do with quantum entanglement. Does anyone know how it's possible and can give an explanation?

Comment: Here are a [couple](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2000/jul/19/laser-smashes-light-speed-record) [links](http://www.physics.uofl.edu/sbmendes/phys%20355%20fall%2007/notes/Chapter%207/406243a0.pdf) for anyone who's about to ask for them.

Comment: Related: [What does Lijun Wang's experiment about supraluminal speed of light in a medium mean?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5326/)

Answer (score -1):

> *There have been conducted many experiments in which light impulses travelled faster than light*

Are you aware of any scientific publication on major journals officially acknowledging such event? As far as the scientific community knows, there is no such evidence. Even though there were any, this would have nothing to do with quantum entanglement anyway, which only applies in non relativistic theories. In quantum field theory (which is the current correctly acknowledged description of the interactions in the universe) the degrees of freedom carried by the fields top up the ones carried by the particles, giving raise to a totally different scenario.